# Is there any way to display different accounts analytics in single page?

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

Is there any way to display different accounts analytics reports in a single page??

Comment: have a look here, it might help
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#multipleDomains

Comment: thanks for replying, the link explains how to combine and display the report as one, but i need to display it as seperate report in a single page, example in single page, 2 gadgets which displays the pageview report. one gadget display a.com's report another b.com's

Comment: I have created a 3rd party service called http://embeddedanalytics.com which allows you to create such widgets and embed them into web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Google Analytics Report Automation using Magic Script - https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/report-automation-magic. As long as you have permission to both accounts you want to pull data from, you can make a dashboard using Google Spreadsheets.